# CSProj contains a reference

Tags: .net, web-services, csproj

I put my csproj for my web service in sourcesafe.

Now inside of the text of the csproj there is a line stating that the webservice is located at
localhost/something

is there a way to not store this info in the csproj so users can move this web service where ever they want?

Answer (score 1):

csproj isn't the place for this; an app.config or a settings file - fine. But not the csproj. End users should never see this. The standard web-reference tools (`wsdl.exe`, `svcutil.exe`, `wse*wsdl.exe`) all support configuration-based locations, for example (from `wsdl.exe`):

> /appsettingurlkey:
>
> The configuration key to use in the code generation to read the default
>   value for the Url property. The default is to not read from the config
>   file. Short form is '/urlkey:'.

If you mean other developers... it can get messy - especially if the devs have separate client/server setups. One trick I've used successfully is to standardise on the IIS mapping, and for all the developers add a "hosts" entry (perhaps "localserver") to their own server (commonly a VM).

Comment: How do I avoid putting the stuff in the csproj?  VS put it in there by default